# Use DBML model but different connection string for same model on different machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I hope the title isnt too confusing.
Here is what I plan to do:

Say I have 10 individual servers located in 10 individual sites across the country.
They have a database and front end desktop application.

Now I have a website for which I have the SAME database structure/model as the 10 servers hold on it. I use LINQ to SQL to set up queries for which I will change the connection string for the DataContext before executing the query.

So basically I have the database on my webserver to serve as a shell if you like for which I can create relational queries based on the webserver database and send the updated information back to whichever server I like by changing the connection string of the datacontext.

As mentioned previously the database structure will always be the same across the individual database and the webserver database. I will be using the DBML structure I have created locally in my code to update data and change the connection string.

Make Sense? Just wanting to confirm if I am missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a situation much like that.  Simplified, our `web.config` file contains entries like:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="server1_ConnectionString" value="Data Source=myServerAddress;..."/>
```

Then in code, you can:

```
use (var dc = new DbDataContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[
                  System.Environment.MachineName.ToLower + "_ConnectingString"]))
{
    ....
```

The code uses a different connection string based on the machine it's run on.

Comment: This approach 'leaks' production configuration details to the developer - not always allowed, never a good idea.

Comment: @belugabob: The developers for Stack Overflow have admin rights to the production servers.  I think the result is awesome. They couldn't have come this far if they had a monthly release cycle where devs had to guess how the production environment really worked. :)

Comment: Fair comment, I suppose it does depend on your working practices and how strict they are.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses everyone. Would yous mind taking another look at my method if i explain more in detail... So yes, I have a bunch of connection strings set up in the web config. Then I have the user name and location of the user in a table in sql. When the user logs into the website I then identify the location of the user and add the connection string to the datacontext ( where there is a match of location against the location name of the connection string in the web.config ) then I perform the query against the relvent database at that location. That is ok to do, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this at runtime simply by passing the required connection string (or a connection) into the data-context as a constructor argument. You can also configure this in configuration - typically in the `connectionStrings` section, but it depends a bit on how the DBML is configured.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I use is to remove the connection string from web.config altogether and define it in the IIS context that contains your website.
By using a namespace-like naming convention like 'YourAppName.ConnectionString', you can avoid conflicts between multiple applications.

The advantages of this approach are manifold...

1. The same deployment files can be used for every environment, with each having its own configuration
2. Deploying a new version should not disturb any existing configuration or require the SysAdmin to edit the web.config every time
3. As the connection string may contain usernames and password, values of these for production environments are not made available to developers.
4. Changes to connection strings do not require the application to be kept in sync.

In order to adopt this approach, you need to be wary of Visual Studio adding a connection string back into the web.config file, and after making changes to your DBML, the default connection string the this uses may get changed. In both cases, just uses your version control system to manage the rollback of these changes.

It might not work for you, but I'm happy doing it this way.

Comment: the only thing is, I need to use a range of connection strings depending on which location the user belongs to when they log in. Which is why i will keep them in the config. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've just read you question again - and I have to say that I don't remember reading it before - did you edit it, to make it clearer?
Anyway, given the explanation above, the answer given by Marc Gravell sounds about right. The only thing I'm not sure about is how stable things will be with multiple users, each using their own data context.